# Why does the SYS_REFCURSOR results in a null value?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Table CKSFLTHD

| FILTERC | DESCR | ACTIVATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Apple Bees Corner | 1 |
| EFG | Elephant Forest Grove | 1 |

Table CKSFLTLN

| FILTERC | SITE | LNUM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Apple Bees Corner | ABC123 |
| EFG | Elephant Forest Grove | EFG456 |

This is what the output should look like, but a null table instead.
I'm going to use the **DISPLAY** to populate a dropdownlist.

| DISPLAY | DATAVAL |
| --- | --- |
| Apple Bees Corner | ABC |

```
OPEN  cv_2 FOR 
  SELECT descr DispVal, filterc DataVal
  FROM cksflthd
  WHERE activate = 1
  AND ( v_showAll = 1
  OR filterc IN ( SELECT *
                  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT filterc
                         FROM cksfltln
                         WHERE  SITE IN ( SELECT SITE
                                          FROM cksfltln
                                          WHERE  filterc = v_userfiltercode )

                         AND ( lnum <> ' '
                               OR filterc = v_userfiltercode ) ) useflt
                        
                  WHERE  filterc IN ( SELECT DISTINCT filterc  
                                      FROM cksfltln
                                      WHERE  SITE IN ( SELECT SITE
                                                       FROM cksfltln
                                                       WHERE  filterc = v_filterCode )

                                      AND ( lnum <> ' '
                                            OR filterc = v_filterCode ) )
                       )
                  );
```

Comment: how about the sql itself, if ran as a statement by the same oracle user executing the stored procedure? Does it also bring back Zero rows?

Comment: Please, add table definitions, sample data and desired output for it. Also clarify the issue: cursor cannot return `null` because it returns result set, which is not a scalar.

Comment: What is the value of `v_userfiltercode`?

Comment: @astentx v_usefiltercode = ABC or any vallue from the filterc column

Comment: @thatjeffsmith  It didn't. The results were the same as what the output should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your code...

Here's what I did, trying to observe what you shared.

```
create table CKSFLTLN
 (FILTERC varchar2(10),
  SITE varchar2(25),
  LNUM varchar2(10));

create table CKSFLTHD
 (FILTERC varchar2(10),
  DESCR varchar2(25),
  ACTIVATE varchar2(25));

insert into cksflthd values ('ABC', 'Applebees Corner', 1);
insert into cksflthd values ('EFG', 'Elephant Forest Grove', 1);

insert into CKSFLTLN values ('ABC', 'Applebees Corner', 'ABC123');
insert into CKSFLTLN values ('EFG', 'Elephant Forest Grove', 'EFG456');





CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refcursor_function 
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
  c SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_userfiltercode varchar2(25) :='ABC';
  v_filterCode varchar2(25) := 'ABC';
  v_showall number(9,0) :=1 ;
BEGIN
  OPEN  c FOR 
  SELECT descr DispVal, filterc DataVal
  FROM cksflthd
  WHERE activate = 1
  AND ( v_showAll = 1
  OR filterc IN ( SELECT *
                  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT filterc
                         FROM cksfltln
                         WHERE  SITE IN ( SELECT SITE
                                          FROM cksfltln
                                          WHERE  filterc = v_userfiltercode )

                         AND ( lnum <> ' '
                               OR filterc = v_userfiltercode ) ) useflt
                        
                  WHERE  filterc IN ( SELECT DISTINCT filterc  
                                      FROM cksfltln
                                      WHERE  SITE IN ( SELECT SITE
                                                       FROM cksfltln
                                                       WHERE  filterc = v_filterCode )

                                      AND ( lnum <> ' '
                                            OR filterc = v_filterCode ) )
                       )
                  );
  RETURN c;
END;
/
```

You only shared the cursor definition, not the PL/SQL program you are using, so I mocked one up, and hardcoded your user values...

Then I executed the function with an anonymous block, or really I asked SQL Developer to execute the function for me. And back came the refcursor...not null.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why the output is null on mine. I'll look into my source code. Thank you so much for your time.